# How to identify different Clients on a NodeJS WebSocketServer, so each one has a unique connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I created a simple WebSocketServer on NodeJS and everything is working fine, but when I connect more then 1 client, it is not working properly. When I send something from client 2, only client 1 gets the message. Is there a way to identify different clients and create a unique connection for each client?

My Websocketserver looks like this:

```
function startupTheWebSocketServer(app, config) {

    var clients=[]
    var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
    console.log("   * Web Socket server will be set up in a moment...")
    var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        httpServer: app,
    });

    var url = "ws://localhost:" + config.server_port

    wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
                var connection = request.accept();
                clients.push(connection)
                console.log("   * WebSocketServer-INFO: A client has connected.")
                var infomsg_to_client = {
                    "WS-INFO": "Welcome. Send me any message you like"
                }
                connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(infomsg_to_client));
```

I tried creating a unique id with, but I am not sure, how to add it to each client:

```
wsServer.getUniqueID = function () {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4();
};
```

Comment: You could simply add the id to the connection like so `connection.id = wsServer.getUniqueID();` or if it requires the user to login you could add the user object or just the user id after they log in.

Comment: @Molda can I add the unique id inside the url variable?

Comment: I don't see why not although i don't see where you use it so hard to tell.